How to display a distance widget by specifying two points(pre-defined) using python vtk?
How to display vtk distance widget without user interaction?
I use to vtk 9.3.1 and python 3.10.9

predefined two points. For examle 0.0,0.0,0.0 and 10.0,0.0,0.0
No user interaction and display distance widget

result
enter image description here
# this is my code
import vtk

renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
render_window = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
render_window.AddRenderer(renderer)

render_window_interactor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
render_window_interactor.SetRenderWindow(render_window)

# prdefined two points
point1 = [0.0, 0.0,0.0]
point2 = [10.0, 0.0,0.0]

line_source = vtk.vtkLineSource()
line_source.SetPoint1(point1)
line_source.SetPoint2(point2)
line_source.Update()

line_mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
line_mapper.SetInputConnection(line_source.GetOutputPort())

line_actor = vtk.vtkActor()
line_actor.SetMapper(line_mapper)
renderer.AddActor(line_actor)

distance_widget = vtk.vtkDistanceWidget()
rep = vtk.vtkDistanceRepresentation2D()
distance_widget.SetRepresentation(rep)
distance_widget.SetInteractor(render_window_interactor)
distance_widget.CreateDefaultRepresentation()
distance_widget.On()

rep.SetPoint1WorldPosition(point1)
rep.SetPoint2WorldPosition(point2)

render_window.Render()
render_window_interactor.Start()

